# ¿Como puedo crear un virtualhost con vagrant y que se vea en una red local?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, virtualbox, vagrant

¿Como puedo crear un virtualhost con vagrant y que se vea en una red local?

En mi caja de vagrant tengo ubuntu y apache y ya logré crear un VirtualHost, pero el problema es que no logro que se vea en la red local desde otra computadora; si alguien pone la dirección ip si se ve, pero si alguien pone el nombre del virtualhost(por ejemplo: `prueba.com`) no se ve nada, solamente se ve la página por defecto del navegador de que hubo un error al tratar de conectar.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? ya que en mi Vagrantfile ya puse la sentencia de:
`config.vm.network "public_network"` y no pasa nada. Si modifico el archivo `hosts` de mi pc física, si logro verlo, pero obviamente no hay que cambiar el hosts de cada máquina que quiera ver la página.

Answer (score 0):

Es que `prueba.com` solo resuelve a la IP correcta si hay un `dns` que sepa de la relación entre nombre e IP, o una linea que lo defina en el archivo `hosts` local de la máquina que hace la petición.

Para lograr esto en una red local hay varias opciones:

- Tener una computadora funcionando como DNS local para toda tu red, configuras el router para que al entregar una IP DHCP también les de la IP de esa máquina como DNS principal, y la de tu ISP o la de google como secundario.
- Conseguir un router compatible con [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) cambiarle el firmware y luego configurar dnsmasq para que levante los dominios que quieras resolver localmente, ademas de reservar las IP para que el DHCP no las entregue a otro dispositivo.
- Usar un plugin para vagrant que levanta un dns temporal (local), por ejemplo [landrush](https://github.com/vagrant-landrush/landrush), las instrucciones para configurar otros dispositivos las podes encontrar en https://github.com/vagrant-landrush/landrush/blob/master/doc/ProxyMobile.adoc , que es basicamente decirle a tus otras computadoras/dispositivos que usen como DNS tu maquina host.
- linux : montar tu propio DNS local con [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) y agregar manualmente las ip/nombres (y luego configurar este dns en los otros dispositivos de la red)